# Old Job and New Job columns SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Is it possible to show 3 new columns - Old Job, New Job, From Date

I have an example of sql below.

```
select
    emp_no,
    emp_name, 
    job_title, 
    valid_from,
    valid_to
    
from 
   tableA
```

I would like to show columns -

Emp No Emp Name, Old Job, New Job, From Date

Old Job and New Job are values from Job Title and From Date is Valid From

[image]

TIA

Yasir

Comment: Looks like `lead / lag` rather then `pivot`

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: attached image as reference

Comment: Image is [not a sample data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557) Please, read [sql tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Comment: Just as an aside, I'm not a big fan of 'magic dates'.  ie:  valid_to = 31/12/9999.  If 'valid_to' date has not yet been determined (for whatever reason)  then just leave it NULL.

Comment: people changed their jobs once in the sample data, what if they change more than once, how will you define new job, will you need more than one new jobs?

Comment: The date of 31/12/9999 is when the emp is still in that job or still with the company. If they have left, there will be a date. Emp can change more than once so thats where thr valid from comes into play so we can determine from a date period which emps have new roles

Answer (score 1):

Try `lag`:

```
select *
from (
  select
    emp_no,
    emp_name,
    lag(job_title) over (partition by emp_no order by valid_from) as old_job,
    job_title as new_job,
    valid_from
  from tableA
)
where old_job is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will give that a try